# Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "." found. on procedure override

Tags: syntax-error, freepascal, lazarus

I know that there are many questions similar to this one but none of them give a answer to mine problem.
I got a Console App generated in Lazarus-ide:

```
program lista;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}
  Classes, SysUtils, CustApp
  { you can add units after this };

type

  { AplikacjaKonsolowa }

  AplikacjaKonsolowa = class(TCustomApplication)
  protected
    procedure DoRun; override;
  public
    constructor Create(TheOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure WriteHelp; virtual;


{ AplikacjaKonsolowa }

type
  wezel = record
    wartosc: integer;
    nastepny: ^wezel;
  end;


procedure AplikacjaKonsolowa.DoRun;                  //error here
var
  ErrorMsg: String;
  wezlyKolejka: array[0..24] of wezel;
  wezlyStosP: array[0..24] of wezel;
  wezlyStosN: array [0..24] of wezel;
  tablicaPar: array[0..1] of array[0..24] of integer;
begin
  // quick check parameters
  ErrorMsg:=CheckOptions('h', 'help');
  if ErrorMsg<>'' then begin
    ShowException(Exception.Create(ErrorMsg));
    Terminate;
    Exit;
  end;

  // parse parameters
  if HasOption('h', 'help') then begin
    WriteHelp;
    Terminate;
    Exit;
  end;

  { add your program here }
  ClrScr;
  gotoXY(10,10);
  writeln('dupa');
  readln;


  // stop program loop
  Terminate;
end;



procedure DodanieLiczbyDoKolejki(kolejka: wezel, liczba: integer);
begin
  while kolejka.nastepny <> -1 do
  begin
    kolejka := kolejka.nastepny^;
  end;
end;




constructor AplikacjaKonsolowa.Create(TheOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(TheOwner);
  StopOnException:=True;
end;

destructor AplikacjaKonsolowa.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure AplikacjaKonsolowa.WriteHelp;
begin
  { add your help code here }
  writeln('Usage: ', ExeName, ' -h');
end;

var
  Application: AplikacjaKonsolowa;
begin
  Application:=AplikacjaKonsolowa.Create(nil);
  Application.Title:='AplikacjaKonsolowa';
  Application.Run;
  Application.Free;
end.
```

I keep getting `Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "." found.` on the DoRun procedure definition. Almost like it would not support `class.method` syntax. I'm guessing the DoRun proc overrides one from TCustomApplication class.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "end;"  after "procedure writehelp; virtual" line to end the class declaration